# DataGridCell set edit-mode in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

In my application I have a `UserControl` with a `DataGrid`. One of the cells in the `DataGrid` is defined like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Alternative path" Width="Auto" MinWidth="60" SortMemberPath="OtherModulePath">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherModulePath}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding OtherModulePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Padding="4,1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseDataGridCellStyle}">
            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" 
                    Value="{Binding OtherModulePath, 
                                    Converter={Converter:AutomationPropertiesNameFromEmptyToSpaceConverter},
                                    FallbackValue=' '}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

If I select the cell and click again with left mouse button the Editing-`TextBox` is shown well.

Above the `DataGrid` there is a `Button`. On a click on this `Button` the `DataGridCell` I've shown should switch into the Editing-Mode, so that the `TextBox` for the OtherModulePath should be visible.

How can I do this with MVVM?

I know how to do it with code-behind, but I have no idea how to start over with databinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGrid has a command called `BeginEditCommand`, you can bind your Button's Command to that command like this:

```
//suppose your grid has name of dg
<Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.BeginEditCommand}"
        CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=dg}">
   <!-- ... -->
</Button>
```